# COPY csv-файл в БД. PostgresSQL. SQL

Tags: html, sql, база-данных, postgresql, csv

Всем привет, нахожусь в небольшой дилемме как решить сложившуюся проблем. Работаю в PostgreSQL

У меня есть функция в которую передаю некие переменные и загружаю CSV-файл, чтобы он заполнил данными таблицу. Этот файл загружает лично пользователь с сайта.

В чем именно проблема:

1) Как определить путь какой нужно указать откуда файл ? (или там нужно просто указать имя файла, который вносит пользователь и передать через переменную, а не целый путь)

2) Не пойму как именно указать путь (как у себя с локального компьютера у меня все получается)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION csv_mark(
num character varying,
lett character varying,
)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$
BEGIN

COPY mark(id_p,mark,id_dis,date) 
FROM 'Тут должен быть путь к файлу' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
END;

$BODY$;
```

Comment: В основном, я не понимаю как передать имя файла который загрузить пользователь в  FROM 'Тут должен быть путь к файлу'

Comment: *как передать имя файла* Как параметр процедуры, ясен пень.